# Android Garbage Collection run too often

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, xamarin.android

The android **garbage collection is performed too often** in my application **causing the application to pause for few milli seconds** often. This gives an ugly feel to use the application. Here is the output of my application. I don't understand ***why the GC is collected when there is still more than 60% of the allocated space is freely available*** for the application. Can any one help to sort this out?

```
04-30 10:37:10.024 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 450K, 65% free 3918K/11072K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 22ms
04-30 10:37:10.076 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 6431 num_hash_entries 6552 sccs size 6552 init 0.00ms df1 11.73ms sort 2.44ms dfs2 2.69ms setup-cb 3.31ms free-data 2.83ms links 123/123/134/2 dfs passes 13106/6675
04-30 10:37:10.076 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 67.65ms, total 67.77ms, bridge 149.55ms promoted 1344K major 1584K los 460K
04-30 10:37:28.900 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 414K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 20ms
04-30 10:37:28.962 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8293 num_hash_entries 8437 sccs size 8437 init 0.00ms df1 14.18ms sort 3.85ms dfs2 3.74ms setup-cb 4.57ms free-data 3.90ms links 144/144/144/1 dfs passes 16874/8581
04-30 10:37:28.962 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 75.21ms, total 75.35ms, bridge 179.08ms promoted 928K major 2512K los 1078K
04-30 10:37:40.035 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 415K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
04-30 10:37:40.109 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8321 num_hash_entries 8495 sccs size 8495 init 0.00ms df1 20.13ms sort 3.42ms dfs2 3.73ms setup-cb 4.82ms free-data 3.88ms links 174/174/174/1 dfs passes 16990/8669
04-30 10:37:40.109 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 78.00ms, total 78.13ms, bridge 195.10ms promoted 848K major 3360K los 1078K
04-30 10:37:46.275 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 469K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
04-30 10:37:46.339 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8366 num_hash_entries 8545 sccs size 8545 init 0.00ms df1 16.65ms sort 3.41ms dfs2 3.75ms setup-cb 4.60ms free-data 3.73ms links 179/179/179/1 dfs passes 17090/8724
04-30 10:37:46.339 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 99.26ms, total 99.46ms, bridge 180.23ms promoted 736K major 4096K los 1078K
04-30 10:37:52.764 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 413K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
04-30 10:37:52.828 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8420 num_hash_entries 10901 sccs size 9914 init 0.00ms df1 23.45ms sort 4.95ms dfs2 33.94ms setup-cb 4.97ms free-data 9.42ms links 5543/5543/201386/155 dfs passes 24864/15457
04-30 10:37:52.828 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 77.37ms, total 77.50ms, bridge 222.91ms promoted 720K major 4816K los 1078K
04-30 10:37:59.867 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 429K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 22ms
04-30 10:37:59.932 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8468 num_hash_entries 10955 sccs size 9968 init 0.00ms df1 23.14ms sort 8.74ms dfs2 37.68ms setup-cb 5.77ms free-data 10.75ms links 5552/5552/206268/159 dfs passes 24975/15520
04-30 10:37:59.932 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 79.11ms, total 79.28ms, bridge 237.01ms promoted 688K major 5504K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:06.707 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 441K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 23ms
04-30 10:38:06.773 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8471 num_hash_entries 10933 sccs size 9946 init 0.00ms df1 24.23ms sort 7.11ms dfs2 36.40ms setup-cb 5.83ms free-data 10.35ms links 5509/5509/188815/146 dfs passes 24913/15455
04-30 10:38:06.773 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 83.46ms, total 83.57ms, bridge 233.86ms promoted 640K major 6144K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:12.649 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 436K, 65% free 3879K/11072K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 20ms
04-30 10:38:12.717 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8532 num_hash_entries 10998 sccs size 10011 init 0.00ms df1 25.97ms sort 8.41ms dfs2 38.58ms setup-cb 6.02ms free-data 10.75ms links 5518/5518/187236/144 dfs passes 25048/15529
04-30 10:38:12.717 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 98.05ms, total 98.50ms, bridge 234.75ms promoted 656K major 6800K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:20.459 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 465K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
04-30 10:38:20.553 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8513 num_hash_entries 10980 sccs size 9993 init 0.00ms df1 26.31ms sort 6.49ms dfs2 36.70ms setup-cb 9.15ms free-data 14.76ms links 5519/5519/187237/144 dfs passes 25012/15512
04-30 10:38:20.553 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 170.23ms, total 170.36ms, bridge 287.15ms promoted 592K major 7392K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:20.613 I/Choreographer(13590): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 10:38:28.985 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 422K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 22ms
04-30 10:38:29.057 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8658 num_hash_entries 11130 sccs size 10143 init 0.00ms df1 24.92ms sort 6.66ms dfs2 38.72ms setup-cb 5.76ms free-data 10.70ms links 5531/5531/202881/157 dfs passes 25319/15674
04-30 10:38:29.057 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 86.76ms, total 86.90ms, bridge 246.82ms promoted 592K major 7984K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:37.678 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 464K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
04-30 10:38:37.745 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8717 num_hash_entries 11155 sccs size 10168 init 0.00ms df1 25.41ms sort 6.09ms dfs2 36.01ms setup-cb 5.71ms free-data 11.76ms links 5483/5483/178115/137 dfs passes 25355/15651
04-30 10:38:37.745 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 83.86ms, total 84.08ms, bridge 236.66ms promoted 544K major 8528K los 2468K
04-30 10:38:45.967 D/dalvikvm(13590): GC_EXPLICIT freed 421K, 65% free 3880K/11072K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 21ms
04-30 10:38:46.037 D/Mono    (13590): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 8744 num_hash_entries 11199 sccs size 10212 init 0.00ms df1 26.69ms sort 6.04ms dfs2 34.30ms setup-cb 5.41ms free-data 10.19ms links 5514/5514/195019/150 dfs passes 25457/15726
04-30 10:38:46.037 D/Mono    (13590): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 82.99ms, total 83.20ms, bridge 242.09ms promoted 608K major 9136K los 2468K
```

Comment: One obvoius question. Are you manually calling it?

Comment: No, I have called the GC.Collect() manually in only one place. That too when the application is disposed. Other than that no manual calls for GC.

Comment: Never can the GarbageCollector manually....

Comment: And the problem is not the GarbageCollector itself. You are creatingeating too many objects which then have to be collected by the GarbageCollector. That the GarbageCollector has to run that often is just a symptom of a flaw in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Set this property on your ListView and it will solve this issue with the GC running constantly while scrolling:

```
CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
```